# Copy entire row from a sheet if value found in another sheet to third sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to solve a problem with VBA/macro or Excel function, but haven't had any luck.

I have 3 sheets:

```
Source
Detail Listing
Final
```

In my **`Source`** sheet I have a list of unique numbers

```
A
-------
111
222
333
444
```

In my **`Detail Listing`** I have data like so:

```
A      B       C        D 
-----------------------------
333    dog     fly      9
777    cat     wasp     2
111    bird    ladybug  8
```

On the **`Final`** sheet I want all the rows from the Details Listing sheet that match values found in the Source Sheet, like so:

```
 A      B       C        D 
---------------------------------
 333    dog     fly      9 
 111    bird    ladybug  8
```

I have tried a `Vlookup` in worksheet but that only gave me a once cell result.  I need the entire row if a match is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of trying to find the values in source over at the detail listting, i would suggest to try doing it reverse, run a for loop over the detail_listing, and for each value in the range A:A, vlookup it in your source, if you get a match, copy the current row in the for loop, otherwise just continue to next cell.

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem I went about it another way like Avishay Cohen suggested.  I added an additional column in my **Detail Listing** worksheet with this formula for the cells:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,Source!A:A,0)),"MATCH", "NOT FOUND")
```

This would list "Match" if there was a match between Column A of my **Detail Listing** worksheet and my **Source** worksheet.  Then I just filtered out the "NOT FOUND" and copied my visible cells to another worksheet.

`ISNUMBER`: Checks whether or not a value is a number - returns TRUE or FALSE
`MATCH`: Returns the relative position of an item in an array that matches a specified value.

I'm sure there are many ways to solve this problem but this one worked for my situation.